# How to display timestamp on a website and terminate a session after a particular time?

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

So I have this code which displays the current timestamp(IST)

```
<?php echo date("D M d, Y "); ?> </b>
    <body onload="digiclock()">
    <div id="txt"></div>
    <script>
   function digiclock()
   {
     var d=new Date();
     var h=d.getHours();
     var m=d.getMinutes();
     var s=d.getSeconds();
     if(s==60)
     {
       s=0;
       m+=1;
     }
     if(m==60)
     {
       m=0;
       h+=1;
     }
     if(h==12)
     {
       h=0;
     }
     var t=h>=12?'PM':'AM';
     document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s+" "+t;
     var t=setTimeout(digiclock,500);
   }
```

How to compress this code and how to use it calculate a time limit for terminate a session. For example, a person is playing quiz and the quiz should terminate after 5 minutes and generate the score based on the questions attempted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is example how to use @rckrd's js code snippet with PHP script called by AJAX.
The example is very basic, just to demonstrate implementation logic.

You cann look for live demo here http://demo1.rrsoft.cz/

Download code here http://demo1.rrsoft.cz/test.zip

index.php with HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="startQuiz()">Start timer</button>

<div id="messages"></div>
<div id="timerView"></div>
<div id="quiz_body"></div>

<script src="ajax.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

ajax.js with needed functions (I used @rckrd snippet, because is a grat example how to use it with PHP)

```
// This function has call php script with quiz answer...

var doAnswer = function(number){
    var response_value = $('[name="qr'+number+'"]').val();
    var response_message = '"Quiz #' + number + ' has successfuly saved';

    $('[name="qr'+number+'"]').prop( "disabled", true );
    $.ajax({
            url: '/answer.php',
            type: 'POST',
            async: true,
            data: {
                quiz: number,
                value: response_value
            },
            success:function(response){
                if(response === 'OK'){
                    $('#messages').html(response_message);
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, type, exception) {
                var _msg = "Service through error: ("+xhr.status+") " + exception.toString();
                var _err = $('#messages');
                    _err.text(_msg).show();
            }
        });
}

// This function just call the php script to render all quiz questions...
var startQuiz = function(){
    $.ajax({
            url: '/quiz.php',
            type: 'GET',
            async: true,
            data: {
                started: true
            },
            success:function(response){
                $('#quiz_body').html(response);
                startTimer();
            },
            error: function(xhr, type, exception) {
                var _msg = "Service through error: ("+xhr.status+") " + exception.toString();
                var _err = $('#messages');
                    _err.text(_msg).show();
            }
        });
}

// Arange elements over time limit
var gameOver = function(){
    $('#header').html('Game over');
    $('#list').hide();
}

// This function manage time limitation logic and is called when quiz has started...
var startTimer = function (){
    var timeLeftInMillis = 1*60*1000;
    var startTime = new Date().getTime();
    var updateTimeInMillis = 25;
    var intervalId = setInterval(function(){
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var diffInMills = now - startTime;
    startTime = new Date().getTime();
    timeLeftInMillis = timeLeftInMillis - diffInMills;
    var oneSecondInMillis = 1000;
    if(timeLeftInMillis < oneSecondInMillis){
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        gameOver();
        return;
    }
    var seconds = Math.floor((timeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 60) ;
    var minutes =  Math.floor((timeLeftInMillis / (1000*60)) % 60);
    document.getElementById("timerView").innerHTML = minutes + ' min, ' +seconds+' sec remaining';
    },updateTimeInMillis);
};
```

The quiz.php called by AJAX:

```
<?php

// very easy list of quizes...
$quiz_template = '
    <h1 id="header">Quiz started!</h1>
    <ul id="list">
        <li>
            Quiz 1 text
            <input type="text" name="qr1" size="5"/>
            <button id="bt1" onclick="doAnswer(1)">Send answer</button>
        </li>
        <li>
            Quiz 2 text
            <input type="text" name="qr2" size="5"/>
            <button id="bt2" onclick="doAnswer(2)">Send answer</button>
        </li>
        <li>
            Quiz 3 text
            <input type="text" name="qr3" size="5"/>
            <button id="bt3" onclick="doAnswer(3)">Send answer</button>
        </li>
        <li>
            Quiz 4 text
            <input type="text" name="qr4" size="5"/>
            <button id="bt4" onclick="doAnswer(4)">Send answer</button>
        </li>
        <li>
            Quiz 5 text
            <input type="text" name="qr5" size="5"/>
            <button id="bt5" onclick="doAnswer(5)">Send answer</button>
        </li>

    </ul>
';

// ... and return it
if((bool) $_GET['started'] === true){
    die($quiz_template);
}
```

And Finaly answer.php

```
<?php

if($_POST){
    // grab all needed posted variables... THIS IS JUST FOR DEMO, BECAUSE IS UNSECURED
    $quizNumber = $_POST['quiz'];
    $quirAnswer = $_POST['value'];

    // do quiz PHP logic here, save answer to DB etc...

    // when php script runs without errors, just return OK
    $error = false;

    if($error === false){
        die('OK');
    }else{
        die($someErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Quite helpful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var gameOver = function(){
  document.getElementById("timerView").innerHTML = 'Game over';
}
var startTimer = function (){
  var timeLeftInMillis = 5*60*1000;
  var startTime = new Date().getTime();
  var updateTimeInMillis = 25;
  var intervalId = setInterval(function(){
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var diffInMills = now - startTime; 
    startTime = new Date().getTime();
    timeLeftInMillis = timeLeftInMillis - diffInMills;
    var oneSecondInMillis = 1000; 
    if(timeLeftInMillis < oneSecondInMillis){
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      gameOver();
      return;
    }
    var seconds = Math.floor((timeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 60) ;
    var minutes =  Math.floor((timeLeftInMillis / (1000*60)) % 60);
    document.getElementById("timerView").innerHTML = minutes + ' min, ' +seconds+' sec remaining';
  },updateTimeInMillis);
};
```

```html
<button onclick="startTimer()">Start timer</button>
<div id="timerView"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to use third part libraries then check out EasyTimer.js plugin, this will solve the issue.
https://albert-gonzalez.github.io/easytimer.js/

or

countdownjs: http://countdownjs.org/demo.html

Answer (score -1):

This is impossible in php, the best way is use JavaScript/Ajax...

Comment: Sure, pls look to my answer, download code link etc.. hope will help...